# Adding audio to iphone app xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avaudioplayer

I am very new to Swift and Xcode.

I am trying to design a simple camera App. I have successfully integrated camera, except I want to play a sound when the camera takes a picture. Im unsure about how to go about this.

Below is my code and I keep getting an error when invoking

> Error : 
>   (EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x38)
>
> in the line audioPlayer.play()

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var sessionOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()


    var kranz = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Din Daa Daa ; George Kranz", ofType: "mp3")!)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        do {let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: kranz, fileTypeHint: nil)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

        }
       catch{
           print("error")
        }
    }



@IBOutlet weak var CameraView: UIView!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    for device in devices {
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back {

            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device as! AVCaptureDevice)
                if captureSession.canAddInput(input){
                    captureSession.addInput(input)
                    sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]

                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){
                        captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                        captureSession.startRunning()
                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight
                        CameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                        previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.CameraView.frame.width / 2, y: self.CameraView.frame.height / 2)
                        previewLayer.bounds = CameraView.frame

                    }
                }

            }
            catch{
                print("ERror")
            }
        }
    }
}


@IBAction func TakePhoto(sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayer.play()
    if let videoConnection = sessionOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){

        sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
            buffer, error in

            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data: imageData)!, nil, nil, nil)

            })
    }
}


}
```

Comment: try printing `kranz` see if you are getting the url.

Comment: When I print kranz it gives me the full URL

Comment: No output from `print(err.debugDescription)` or `print("error")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit import AVFoundation

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
   var sessionOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
   var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
   var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

   override viewDidLoad(){
      super.viewDidLoad()

          prepareMusic("LazerNoise",type : "mp3" )      
         } 

   func prepareMusic(name :String! , type :String!){

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType: type)
        let soundURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    do{
       try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL)
       audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    }
  catch let err as NSError
   {
    print(err.debugDescription)
  }

 }

 func playNstop(){

    if audioPlayer.playing{

      audioPlayer.stop()
   }else{

    audioPlayer.play()
   }
 }



@IBOutlet weak var CameraView: UIView!

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

  let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
   for device in devices {
    if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back {

        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device as! AVCaptureDevice)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input){
                captureSession.addInput(input)
                sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]

                if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){
                    captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                    captureSession.startRunning()
                    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                    previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.LandscapeRight
                    CameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                    previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.CameraView.frame.width / 2, y: self.CameraView.frame.height / 2)
                    previewLayer.bounds = CameraView.frame

                }
            }

        }
        catch{
            print("ERror")
        }
      }
    }
  }


@IBAction func TakePhoto(sender: UIButton) {

 audioPlayer.play()
 if let videoConnection = sessionOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
        buffer, error in

        let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data: imageData)!, nil, nil, nil)

        })
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Where would the above code be inputted? I tried putting in this code and changing the pathForResource to my file and I am not getting that same error now right at playNstop()

Comment: I added the new code at the bottom on the question for reference

Comment: I receive that error within the playNstop() function on the "if audioPlayer.playing{"  line.

Comment: Had a small error in my code on the , it works awesome now. Thank you